# Django 2 How to use forign keys of one model in another model

Tags: django, django-queryset, models

I am new to django and I am building a cricket club management website in django. There are teams, players, grounds and match apps. In team apps.

**Players Model:**

```
class Players(models.Model):
    player_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    player_email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    player_team = models.ManyToManyField(Teams)
```

**Teams Model:**

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team_home_ground = models.ForeignKey(Grounds, on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Match Model:**

```
class AddMatch(models.Model):
    match_team_1 = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team1')
    match_team_2 = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team2')
    match_ground = models.ForeignKey(Grounds, on_delete=None)
    match_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

Now I want to add another model AddMatchRecod to submit match record and I will make form based on that model. In AddMatchRecod I want to have a field winning_team field, a drop down list of two fields from AddMatch model match_team_1 and match_team_2 as choices. Teams table has many teams I only want to present two teams that are participating in the match. How would I get that.

```
class MatchAddData(models.Model):
    team1 = ??
    team2 = ??
```

Second question. There is a model PlayersRecords which stores players data. There are 100s of players how would I get the 11 or 12 players that are part of team1 and team2 and display separately PlayerRecord model fields in form for each player.

**Player Record Model:**

```
class PlayersRecords(models.Model):
    player_full_name = models.ForeignKey(Players, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_total_runs = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    player_total_matches = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    player_total_fours = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    player_total_sixes = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    player_total_centuries = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    player_total_fifties = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you named the model `AddMatch`? Since an `AddMatch` is not really an "entity", this looks like strange *nomenclature*.

Comment: I want to add a match first and show that on the site these matches are coming in future. Then after a match has happened then I want to add results of that match. That is why I kept AddMatch model separate from MatchAddData model and referenced AddMatch with MatchAddData. I am not sure how to do it. I am new in programing and building a complex site.

`class MatchAddData(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(AddMatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: For the second question could you combine your Player and PlayerRecord models? Then you can assign your players to a team and easily edit their records if needed.